# sklearn tools for assigning probabilities to the labels

Tags: machine-learning

I am using `sklearn` tools in a ML project. I have doubts about what I am doing. It is about a binary classification using 1 and 0 as labels. The first line of code below provides a list of 1's and 0's. The second line of code below provides an array of lists consisting of float numbers. The two entries of each list sum up to 1. My question is, which of the entries in the lists is referring to the 1 and which to the 0 label ? I could not find that in the documentation.

```
 y_predict_lnrna = classifier.predict(X_new)
 y_predict_lnrna2 = classifier.predict_proba(X_new)
```

Comment: The probability vector should be $p(0)$ on the left and $p(1)$ on the right.

Comment: @Dave Many thanks, it's great help. Can you refer me to the documentation in this regard? I need to be sure  100%. In the `sklearn` documentation I found it very ambiguous.